# How to create a custom Firefox installation?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

I would like to install a custom version of Firefox on several computers.  I would like to customize Firefox in the following ways:

1. Set Firefox's language to English.
2. Set the language of Firefox's default search engine to English.
3. Set Firefox to open new tabs by default (instead of new windows).
4. Set Firefox's home page to a particular web site.
5. Pre-installed with a PDF viewer.
6. Pre-installed with a few additional plugins.

I'd like to simply create a single custom version of Firefox that I can distribute to these other computers, rather than doing all of the setup by hand.  How might I do that?

Edit: I will probably install these on Windows machines but am currently working from a Mac.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an answer to my own question.  [CCK2](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/cck2wizard/) - a plugin for creating plugins and modifying Firefox settings, offers a unified solution.  It addresses 2,3,4, and 6.  For 5, Firefox comes with its own default PDF viewer, and for 1, I'd need to select the right version of Firefox.